# How to test mobile apps on Azure platform?

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a mobile app written native for each platform(Android, IOS and windows).
I want to test my application on a cloud based real mobile devices using Microsoft's Azure platform. I have no Idea if Azure provides such service.

1. Does Azure provides mobile app testing on real mobile devices for apps written on native code for IOS, Android and windows ?
2. Does Azure provides mobile app testing on real mobile devices for apps written on cross platform codebase(Xamrin, phonegap, ionic etc) for IOS, Android and windows ?
3. Please provide the link and name of the service.
4. I do not want to host any web apps or the matter of fact I do not want any other service from Microsoft like the Saas etc. I just want a plain mobile app testing service from Azure.
5. Does Azure support all the platforms. Please provide me a link for the proof.

Thank in Advance :)

Comment: Why don't you start reading https://azure.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 3):

Azure does not provide testing services for mobile apps. 
One of the better app testing services out there is Xamarin Test Cloud. Feel free to check it out here - https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud